# Drupal6 - Outputting a CSV with a MENU_CALLBACK

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, csv, drupal-modules

I would like to output a csv file with a drupal 6 module. This is the code I have, but it's hacked together with some of it in my custom theme and some of it in my module. Is there anyway I can move all of it into my module?

```
///////////////////////////
// csv.module <- a custom module
///////////////////////////
function csv_menu() {

    $items = array();

    $items['csv/results'] = array (
        'page callback' => 'csv_results_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function csv_theme() {
    $items = array();

    $items['csv_results'] = array(
        'arguments' => array(),
    );

    return $items;
}

function csv_results_page() {
    return generate_csv_results();
}

function theme_csv_results() {
    return generate_csv_results();
}

function generate_csv_results() {
    return "header1,header2,header3,header4\nval1,val2,val3,val4\n";
}


//////////////////////////////
// page-csv-results.tpl.php <- in my theme. I would like it all contained in the module.
//////////////////////////////
<?php
    //!TODO: Change Content Type Header
    print theme('csv_results');
```

---

**EDIT**

Below is an updated version for anyone with a similar question. Thanks goes to chx!

```
///////////////////////////
// csv.module <- a custom module
///////////////////////////
function csv_menu() {

    $items = array();

    $items['csv/results'] = array (
        'page callback' => 'csv_results_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function csv_results_page() {
    //Take a look at the Nikit's response on header stuff. This might be incorrect.
    header('Content-Type: text/x-comma-separated-values');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
    header('Cache-Control: private',false); // required for certain browser
    print generate_csv_results();
}

function generate_csv_results() {
    return "header1,header2,header3,header4\nval1,val2,val3,val4\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputting CSV should be done by just printing stuff in the page callback, if you `return` as you do it will be in the current theme, surrounded by HTML and you dont need that.

Comment: I'll try this out as it's closer to what I want to do. There's a ajax message that accesses a static CSV now and it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark this as an answer. I just got around to testing it out and fixing the module. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is my simplified version of exporting csv file, add this code into csv_results_page(). Here used query, but can be other thing (like arrays, file listing, etc):

```
/**
 * Export to cvs
 */
function _YOURMODULENAME_csv_export() {
  $delimiter = "\t"; // This is tab delimiter, can be other

  $temp = file_directory_temp();

  $file = tempnam(realpath($temp), 'csv');
  if (!$fp = fopen($file, 'a')) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The file for exported could not be created. Refer to the site administrator'), 'error');
    return;
  }

  $title = "Some title for csv\n"; // you can remove it, if don't want title in csv

  $title .= implode($delimiter, array('Column name 1','Column name 2')). "\n"; // Add all columns titles here, it should mutch query result fields below

  fwrite($fp, $title);

  $query = 'WRITE HERE SOME CODE THAT SHOULD RESULT QUERY AND  RETURN fields in order described in $title above';
  $result = db_query($query);
  while ($data = db_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows = implode($delimiter, $data);
    fwrite($fp, $rows."\n");
  }

  fclose($fp);

  $header = array();

  $header[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
  $header[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate';
  $header[] = 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="exort_'.date('Ymd',time()).'.csv";'; // This is file name
  $header[] = 'Content-Type: text/x-comma-separated-values';
  $header[] = 'Content-Length: '.filesize($file);
  $header[] = 'Connection: close';

  file_transfer($file, $header);
  file_delete($file);

  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know that you could generate and transfer a file like that.

Comment: @Nikit, this worked great for me, thank you. One little wrinkle though, drupal_set_message doesn't really work in this context as you aren't usually going to "return" to a page/view that can show it. So I simply used print() instead to ensure something was made visible if there was a problem that couldn't be caught before using this function as a menu callback.